# UPDATE or SET a Column in SQL after SELECT DISTINCT

Tags: mysql

I'm beginning in SQL and don't know how to do that.

What I am looking for is a way to give the same ID to column which as an identical value.

This is my table :

[image]

I want `'afrique du sud'` for exemple to have the same `'id_country'`
How can I do that ?

I tried `SELECT DISTINCT country FROM  country SET id_country = id_country + 1` but it didn't work and I guess it is because SELECT don't mix up the value (that would make sense).

Any help would be gladly accepted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to set up a separate table called `country`.  It will have 2 columns where each country will have an individual `id` and a `name`.  You can then set the `id_country` to the `id` from the `country` table with the following:

```
UPDATE table t, country_table c SET t.id_country = c.id WHERE t.country = c.name
```

Comment: Perfect sorry for long time before answer I had urgent thing to do. Thank you all !

Answer (score 0):

The first thing you want to do is to group your table by country, and always select the maximum id for each country.

```
SELECT description_country,  max(id) id
FROM country 
GROUP BY description_country
```

When you have this you want to update your original table with the id that came out of the previous query where the description matches.

```
UPDATE country c
SET ID_COUNTRY=X.id
FROM 
(SELECT description_country,  max(id) id
FROM country 
GROUP BY description_country) X
WHERE c.description_country = x.description_country
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use this query:

```
update country_table set id_country = 
(select max_id from (select max(id) as max_id, country from country_table group by  country_table.country ) as temp_table
 where temp_table.country = country_table.country)
```